# Multiprocess in python Flask-Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, gunicorn

I'm new in multiprocessing module and i have a question about it.

I use Gunicorn as wsgi to run my flask application. I understand that gunicorn use workers (based on cpu cores)  to handle request in parallel way.
But I have a  heavy process in my flask app, i wanted use multiprocess module to improve response time , however every time i call :

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=[arg1..])
```

gunicorn restart a worker and makes response time longer.

There any problem using multiprocessing module inside a flask app running in gunicorn ?

EDIT ->>

When a worker starts , its Id is writed in my logfile.

This is my code. I have 400 items in *stores* list:

```py
  from multiprocessing import Queue , Process

  queue_stores = Queue()
  list_process = []

  def heavy_func(id , queue) :
      # Do something
      queue.put(resp)

  for store in stores :
     proc = Process(target=heavy_func, args=[store.id,queue_stores ])
  
  for proc in list_process :
     proc.start()

  for procin list_process :
     proc.join()

  while not queue_stores.empty() :
      df_final = df_final.append(queue_tiendas.get(), sort=False)
```

When *proc.start()* is called my logfile starts to write new id workers. I dont understand why.

Comment: Can you share more code?

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn and multiprocessing are multiprocessing module and it might cause trouble when you try to invoke multiple processes inside of a single process. Use multiprocessing.dummy instead